# When are locks necessary to protect data shared by coroutines

Tags: python, locking, python-asyncio

I was reading the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61647815/do-coroutines-require-locks-when-reading-writing-a-shared-resource) and was curious about this statement:

> That said, since coroutines are based on cooperative multitasking instead of preemptive, you can sometimes guarantee that locks are unnecessary in cases where they would be necessary with threads. For example, if there are no points at which any coroutine could yield control during a critical section, then you don't need a lock.

I just got started learning about `asyncio`.  My understanding is that a coroutine can only yield control to another when using either `await` or `yield from`.  Is this correct?

For context, suppose I have a global variable, `foo`, which is initialized to `None` and only ever accessed by coroutines.

In one coroutine, I have

```py
global foo
foo = Foo()
await foo.some_async_func()
foo = None
```

In another coroutine, I have

```py
if foo is not None:
    foo.some_synchronous_func()
```

Assuming that the value of `foo` is only ever set by the first coroutine, is there any reason why I would need to protect the setting/checking of its value by a lock?

Comment: You are correct.